# Removing 1 line of code from all php files

Tags: linux, php, ssh, unix

I can see same code under all php files.

Starting from

```
<?php $rfghoh = '*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssu6
```

And end

```
$rfghoh=$yuoopi-1; ?>
```

**I am just looking for script using which only first line of php code get remove not the entire php file.**

I tried `find -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '/<?php $rfghoh/,/?>/d' '{}' \;`

But its removing all content under files though I need to remove just under those tags.

Thanks

Comment: You also need to secure your server, so that you do not get hacked again. Just removing this code won't be sufficient for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a compromised server?](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: Hi, I did try as per http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server but it did not work.

I am just missing a little code using which whole php file don't get empty only that content under first php tags.

Comment: I wanted to ask you for a quick answer regarding the code found in your script Starting from `<?php $rfghoh = '*f%)sfxpmpusut)tpqssu6` And end `$rfghoh=$yuoopi-1; ?>` Did you find the cause of it? Do you use Strato as a hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

use Dreamweaver to find and replace using the folder settings instead of file. (search and replace in all files in a folder)

you can use regex to match the lines you need to replace if the middle of each is different, if the lines are identical its not needed.

but thats just going to get your site back to where it was before being hacked. once cleaned you will need to secure your code.